# No results returned (not correct) from query for number of NULLs, MinValue,MaxValue and AvgValue

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms-2016

[image]

I have a query below that should bring back records for the number of NULL records, the MinValue of a column, MaxValue and AvgValue. However, the query runs but does not bring back records, just the column headers, when it definitely should. Can you correct my code to show where I'm going wrong? The calculated fields should only apply to numeric, float, decimal and other selected data types, as defined in the query below.

```
DECLARE @schemaName AS sysname;
    DECLARE @tableName AS sysname;
    DECLARE @columnName AS sysname;
    DECLARE @schema_id AS int;
    DECLARE @object_id AS int;
    DECLARE @column_id AS int;
    DECLARE @isNullable AS bit;
    DECLARE @lastSchema_id AS int;
    DECLARE @lastTable_id AS int;
    DECLARE @recordCount AS bigint;
    DECLARE @MinValue As int;
    DECLARE @MaxValue As int;
    DECLARE @AvgValue As int;
    DECLARE @nullCnt AS bigint;
    DECLARE @SQL as nvarchar(max);
    DECLARE @paramDefinition NVARCHAR(max);

    if exists(select name from tempdb..sysobjects where name LIKE'#Columns%')
    DROP TABLE #Columns;

    CREATE TABLE #Columns (
        schema_id int,
        object_id int,
        column_id int,
        schemaName sysname,
        tableName sysname,
        columnName sysname,
        recordCnt bigint,
        MinValue int,
        MaxValue int,
        AvgValue int,
        nullCnt bigint,
        nullPct numeric(38,35) );

    -- Set to the @lastSchema_id and @lastTable_id to NULL so that the first 
    --  loop through the cursor the record count is generated.
    SET @lastSchema_id = NULL;
    SET @lastTable_id = NULL;

    -- List of all the user schemas.tables.columns
    --  in the database
    DECLARE c_Cursor CURSOR FOR
    SELECT schemas.schema_id
         , all_objects.object_id
         , all_columns.column_id
         , schemas.name AS schemaName
         , all_objects.name AS tableName
         , all_columns.name AS columnName
         , all_columns.is_nullable
      FROM sys.schemas
     INNER JOIN sys.all_objects
        ON schemas.schema_id = all_objects.schema_id
       AND all_objects.type = 'U'
     INNER JOIN sys.all_columns
        ON all_objects.object_id = all_columns.object_id
         WHERE all_objects.type LIKE '%int%'
         OR all_objects.type LIKE '%float%' 
         OR all_objects.type LIKE '%decimal%'
         OR all_objects.type LIKE '%numeric%'
         OR all_objects.type LIKE '%real%'
         OR all_objects.type LIKE '%money%'
     ORDER BY schemas.schema_id
         , all_objects.object_id
         , all_columns.column_id;

    OPEN c_Cursor;

    FETCH NEXT FROM c_Cursor
     INTO @schema_id
        , @object_id
        , @column_id
        , @schemaName
        , @tableName
        , @columnName
        , @isNullable;

    -- Loop through the cursor
    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    BEGIN

        -- Get the record count for the table we are currently working on if this is
        --  the first time we are encountering the table.
        IF ( ( @schema_id <> @lastSchema_id ) OR ( @object_id <> @lastTable_id )
          OR ( @lastSchema_id IS NULL ) OR ( @lastTable_id IS NULL ) )
        BEGIN

            SET @SQL = N'SELECT @recordCount = COUNT(1) FROM ' + QUOTENAME(@schemaName) + N'.' + QUOTENAME(@tableName) + ';';
            SET @paramDefinition = N'@recordCount bigint OUTPUT';

            exec sp_executesql @SQL,
                               @paramDefinition,
                               @recordCount = @recordCount OUTPUT;

        END

        -- Get the min value for the table 

    IF ( ( @schema_id <> @lastSchema_id ) OR ( @object_id <> @lastTable_id )
          OR ( @lastSchema_id IS NULL ) OR ( @lastTable_id IS NULL ) )
        BEGIN

            SET @SQL = N'SELECT @MinValue = COUNT(1) FROM ' + QUOTENAME(@schemaName) + N'.' + QUOTENAME(@tableName) + ';';
            SET @paramDefinition = N'@MinValue int OUTPUT';

            exec sp_executesql @SQL,
                               @paramDefinition,
                               @MinValue = @MinValue OUTPUT;

        END

        --Get the max value for the table

        IF ( ( @schema_id <> @lastSchema_id ) OR ( @object_id <> @lastTable_id )
          OR ( @lastSchema_id IS NULL ) OR ( @lastTable_id IS NULL ) )
        BEGIN

            SET @SQL = N'SELECT @MaxValue = COUNT(1) FROM ' + QUOTENAME(@schemaName) + N'.' + QUOTENAME(@tableName) + ';';
            SET @paramDefinition = N'@MaxValue int OUTPUT';

            exec sp_executesql @SQL,
                               @paramDefinition,
                               @MaxValue = @MaxValue OUTPUT;

        END

        --Get the avg value for the table
    IF ( ( @schema_id <> @lastSchema_id ) OR ( @object_id <> @lastTable_id )
          OR ( @lastSchema_id IS NULL ) OR ( @lastTable_id IS NULL ) )
        BEGIN

            SET @SQL = N'SELECT @AvgValue = COUNT(1) FROM ' + QUOTENAME(@schemaName) + N'.' + QUOTENAME(@tableName) + ';';
            SET @paramDefinition = N'@AvgValue int OUTPUT';

            exec sp_executesql @SQL,
                               @paramDefinition,
                               @AvgValue = @AvgValue OUTPUT;

        END



        -- If the column is NOT NULL, there is no reason to do a count
        --  Set the nullCnt and nullPct to 0
        IF ( @isNullable = 0 )
        BEGIN


            INSERT INTO #Columns
                 ( [schema_id]
                 , [object_id]
                 , column_id
                 , schemaName
                 , tableName
                 , columnName
                 , recordCnt
                 , nullCnt
                 , nullPct )
            VALUES
                 ( @schema_id
                 , @object_id
                 , @column_id
                 , @schemaName
                 , @tableName
                 , @columnName
                 , @recordCount
                 , 0
                 , 0.0 );
        END
        -- If the column is NULL, count the number of NULL fields in the table.
        ELSE
        BEGIN

            SET @SQL = N'SELECT @nullCnt = COUNT(1) FROM ' + QUOTENAME(@schemaName) + N'.' + QUOTENAME(@tableName) + 
                       N' WHERE ' + QUOTENAME(@columnName) + N' IS NULL;';
            SET @paramDefinition = N'@nullCnt bigint OUTPUT';

            PRINT @SQL;

            exec sp_executesql @SQL,
                               @paramDefinition,
                               @nullCnt = @nullCnt OUTPUT;

            INSERT INTO #Columns
                 ( [schema_id]
                 , [object_id]
                 , column_id
                 , schemaName
                 , tableName
                 , columnName
                 , recordCnt
                 , nullCnt
                 , nullPct )
            VALUES
                 ( @schema_id
                 , @object_id
                 , @column_id
                 , @schemaName
                 , @tableName
                 , @columnName
                 , @recordCount
                 , @nullCnt
                 -- USE NULLIF in case there are no recods in the table
                 , ISNULL( @nullCnt * 1.0 / NULLIF( @recordCount, 0) * 100.0, 0 ) );

        END

        -- Set the @lastSchema_id and @lastTable_id so that on 
        --  the next loop, if it's the same table there is no 
        --  need to recount the columns for the table.
        SET @lastSchema_id = @schema_id;
        SET @lastTable_id = @object_id;

        FETCH NEXT FROM c_Cursor
         INTO @schema_id
            , @object_id
            , @column_id
            , @schemaName
            , @tableName
            , @columnName
            , @isNullable;

    END;

    CLOSE c_Cursor;
    DEALLOCATE c_Cursor;

    SELECT *
      FROM #Columns;
```

Comment: `PRINT @SQL;` is your best friend. Don't try to debug the SQL that is creating the Dynamic SQL, debug the generated SQL. Then propagate any changes to the SQL that generates the dynamic SQL. Most likely you'll have a look at the generated SQL and find the problems quite quickly.

Comment: Cursors and dynamic SQL? If you post some sample data and what you'd like to see at the end I'm sure someone will have a solution that uses a standard set based SQL statement...

Comment: Tried to print @SQL  - generated error message saying I 'must declare the scalar variable "@SQL".'

Comment: Any more solutions please?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the first query that you use for the cursor:

```
   SELECT schemas.schema_id
         , all_objects.object_id
         , all_columns.column_id
         , schemas.name AS schemaName
         , all_objects.name AS tableName
         , all_columns.name AS columnName
         , all_columns.is_nullable
      FROM sys.schemas
     INNER JOIN sys.all_objects
        ON schemas.schema_id = all_objects.schema_id
       AND all_objects.type = 'U'
     INNER JOIN sys.all_columns
        ON all_objects.object_id = all_columns.object_id
         WHERE all_objects.type LIKE '%int%'
         OR all_objects.type LIKE '%float%' 
         OR all_objects.type LIKE '%decimal%'
         OR all_objects.type LIKE '%numeric%'
         OR all_objects.type LIKE '%real%'
         OR all_objects.type LIKE '%money%'
     ORDER BY schemas.schema_id
         , all_objects.object_id
         , all_columns.column_id;
```

If you check closely, you do an `INNER JOIN` on `all_object.type = 'U'` so all types must be `U` but then in the `WHERE` you do additional filter on the same oclumn with column types which will always be false since you already filter by type `U`.

I think you wanted to filter by column data type, in which you will have to do an additional join and filter correctly, like the following:

```
SELECT 
    schemas.schema_id
    , all_objects.object_id
    , all_columns.column_id
    , schemas.name AS schemaName
    , all_objects.name AS tableName
    , all_columns.name AS columnName
    , all_columns.is_nullable
FROM 
    sys.schemas
    INNER JOIN sys.all_objects
    ON schemas.schema_id = all_objects.schema_id
    AND all_objects.type = 'U'
    INNER JOIN sys.all_columns
    ON all_objects.object_id = all_columns.object_id

    INNER JOIN sys.types 
    ON all_columns.system_type_id = types.system_type_id
    AND all_columns.user_type_id = types.user_type_id

WHERE 
    types.name LIKE '%int%'
    OR types.name LIKE '%float%' 
    OR types.name LIKE '%decimal%'
    OR types.name LIKE '%numeric%'
    OR types.name LIKE '%real%'
    OR types.name LIKE '%money%'
ORDER BY 
    schemas.schema_id
    , all_objects.object_id
    , all_columns.column_id;
```

EDIT: Here is the corrected full script. Errors mentioned below.

```
DECLARE @schemaName AS sysname;
DECLARE @tableName AS sysname;
DECLARE @columnName AS sysname;
DECLARE @schema_id AS int;
DECLARE @object_id AS int;
DECLARE @column_id AS int;
DECLARE @isNullable AS bit;
DECLARE @lastSchema_id AS int;
DECLARE @lastTable_id AS int;
DECLARE @recordCount AS bigint;
DECLARE @MinValue As int;
DECLARE @MaxValue As int;
DECLARE @AvgValue As int;
DECLARE @nullCnt AS bigint;
DECLARE @SQL as nvarchar(max);
DECLARE @paramDefinition NVARCHAR(max);

if exists(select name from tempdb..sysobjects where name LIKE'#Columns%')
DROP TABLE #Columns;

CREATE TABLE #Columns (
    schema_id int,
    object_id int,
    column_id int,
    schemaName sysname,
    tableName sysname,
    columnName sysname,
    recordCnt bigint,
    MinValue int,
    MaxValue int,
    AvgValue int,
    nullCnt bigint,
    nullPct numeric(38,35) );

-- Set to the @lastSchema_id and @lastTable_id to NULL so that the first 
--  loop through the cursor the record count is generated.
SET @lastSchema_id = NULL;
SET @lastTable_id = NULL;

-- List of all the user schemas.tables.columns
--  in the database
DECLARE c_Cursor CURSOR FOR
SELECT
    schemas.schema_id
    , all_objects.object_id
    , all_columns.column_id
    , schemas.name AS schemaName
    , all_objects.name AS tableName
    , all_columns.name AS columnName
    , all_columns.is_nullable
FROM 
    sys.schemas
    INNER JOIN sys.all_objects
    ON schemas.schema_id = all_objects.schema_id
    AND all_objects.type = 'U'
    INNER JOIN sys.all_columns
    ON all_objects.object_id = all_columns.object_id

    INNER JOIN sys.types 
    ON all_columns.system_type_id = types.system_type_id
    AND all_columns.user_type_id = types.user_type_id

WHERE 
    types.name LIKE '%int%'
    OR types.name LIKE '%float%' 
    OR types.name LIKE '%decimal%'
    OR types.name LIKE '%numeric%'
    OR types.name LIKE '%real%'
    OR types.name LIKE '%money%'
ORDER BY 
    schemas.schema_id
    , all_objects.object_id
    , all_columns.column_id;

OPEN c_Cursor;

FETCH NEXT FROM c_Cursor
 INTO @schema_id
    , @object_id
    , @column_id
    , @schemaName
    , @tableName
    , @columnName
    , @isNullable;

-- Loop through the cursor
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN

    -- Get the record count for the table we are currently working on if this is
    --  the first time we are encountering the table.
    IF ( ( @schema_id <> @lastSchema_id ) OR ( @object_id <> @lastTable_id )
      OR ( @lastSchema_id IS NULL ) OR ( @lastTable_id IS NULL ) )
    BEGIN

        SET @SQL = N'SELECT @recordCount = COUNT(1) FROM ' + QUOTENAME(@schemaName) + N'.' + QUOTENAME(@tableName) + ';';
        SET @paramDefinition = N'@recordCount bigint OUTPUT';

        exec sp_executesql @SQL,
                           @paramDefinition,
                           @recordCount = @recordCount OUTPUT;

    END

    -- Get the min value for the table 

IF ( ( @schema_id <> @lastSchema_id ) OR ( @object_id <> @lastTable_id )
      OR ( @lastSchema_id IS NULL ) OR ( @lastTable_id IS NULL ) )
    BEGIN

        SET @SQL = N'SELECT @MinValue = MIN(' + QUOTENAME(@columnName) + N') FROM ' + QUOTENAME(@schemaName) + N'.' + QUOTENAME(@tableName) + ';';
        SET @paramDefinition = N'@MinValue int OUTPUT';

        exec sp_executesql @SQL,
                           @paramDefinition,
                           @MinValue = @MinValue OUTPUT;

    END

    --Get the max value for the table

    IF ( ( @schema_id <> @lastSchema_id ) OR ( @object_id <> @lastTable_id )
      OR ( @lastSchema_id IS NULL ) OR ( @lastTable_id IS NULL ) )
    BEGIN

        SET @SQL = N'SELECT @MaxValue = MAX(' + QUOTENAME(@columnName) + N') FROM ' + QUOTENAME(@schemaName) + N'.' + QUOTENAME(@tableName) + ';';
        SET @paramDefinition = N'@MaxValue int OUTPUT';

        exec sp_executesql @SQL,
                           @paramDefinition,
                           @MaxValue = @MaxValue OUTPUT;

    END

    --Get the avg value for the table
IF ( ( @schema_id <> @lastSchema_id ) OR ( @object_id <> @lastTable_id )
      OR ( @lastSchema_id IS NULL ) OR ( @lastTable_id IS NULL ) )
    BEGIN

        SET @SQL = N'SELECT @AvgValue = AVG(' + QUOTENAME(@columnName) + N') FROM ' + QUOTENAME(@schemaName) + N'.' + QUOTENAME(@tableName) + ';';
        SET @paramDefinition = N'@AvgValue int OUTPUT';

        exec sp_executesql @SQL,
                           @paramDefinition,
                           @AvgValue = @AvgValue OUTPUT;

    END



    -- If the column is NOT NULL, there is no reason to do a count
    --  Set the nullCnt and nullPct to 0
    IF ( @isNullable = 0 )
    BEGIN


        INSERT INTO #Columns
             ( [schema_id]
             , [object_id]
             , column_id
             , schemaName
             , tableName
             , columnName
             , recordCnt
             , nullCnt
             , nullPct
             ,MinValue
             ,MaxValue
             ,AvgValue )
        SELECT
             @schema_id
             , @object_id
             , @column_id
             , @schemaName
             , @tableName
             , @columnName
             , @recordCount
             , 0
             , 0
             , @MinValue
             , @MaxValue
             , @AvgValue
    END
    -- If the column is NULL, count the number of NULL fields in the table.
    ELSE
    BEGIN

        SET @SQL = N'SELECT @nullCnt = COUNT(1) FROM ' + QUOTENAME(@schemaName) + N'.' + QUOTENAME(@tableName) + 
                   N' WHERE ' + QUOTENAME(@columnName) + N' IS NULL;';
        SET @paramDefinition = N'@nullCnt bigint OUTPUT';

        PRINT @SQL;

        exec sp_executesql @SQL,
                           @paramDefinition,
                           @nullCnt = @nullCnt OUTPUT;

        INSERT INTO #Columns
             ( [schema_id]
             , [object_id]
             , column_id
             , schemaName
             , tableName
             , columnName
             , recordCnt
             , nullCnt
             , nullPct
             ,MinValue
             ,MaxValue
             ,AvgValue )
        SELECT
              @schema_id
             , @object_id
             , @column_id
             , @schemaName
             , @tableName
             , @columnName
             , @recordCount
             , @nullCnt
             -- USE NULLIF in case there are no recods in the table
             , ISNULL( @nullCnt * 1.0 / NULLIF( @recordCount, 0) * 100.0, 0 )
             , @MinValue
             , @MaxValue
             , @AvgValue

    END

    -- Set the @lastSchema_id and @lastTable_id so that on 
    --  the next loop, if it's the same table there is no 
    --  need to recount the columns for the table.
    SET @lastSchema_id = @schema_id;
    SET @lastTable_id = @object_id;

    FETCH NEXT FROM c_Cursor
     INTO @schema_id
        , @object_id
        , @column_id
        , @schemaName
        , @tableName
        , @columnName
        , @isNullable;

END;

CLOSE c_Cursor;
DEALLOCATE c_Cursor;

SELECT *
  FROM #Columns;
```

Errors:

- You were calculating the avg, min and max as `COUNT` instead of the correct operation.
- The avg, min and max weren't applied to the correct column, it was always a hard-coded 1.
- You were calculating the avg, min and max but not inserting them in your temporary table.

Comment: Hi EzLo, thanks for your code and solution. Your code does work but it doesn't quite give me what I need, as I want to generate the record count, null count, null percent and the min value, max value and avg value of each column as stated in the code. I have add an image of a sample result dataset for you if you'd like to have a look?

Comment: Ok, I'm getting an error: 'arithmetic overflow error converting expression to data type int.'  For row SELECT @nullCnt = COUNT(1) FROM [SystemName].[Table] WHERE [Id] IS NULL;

Comment: Use `COUNT_BIG()` instead of `COUNT()` and make sure your variable is also BIG INT. You might want to filter out system tables on your cursor select.

Comment: Same Error I'm afraid.

Comment: Either you have a table that overflows a big int or there is a typo in your dynamic sql. Use print to see which table is failing and check if it's one or another. You can use TRY CATCH to control errors and keep going.

Comment: So using PRINT SQL, it's mostly the id fields from all the tables that are failing, and the statement is like the sql statement in my previous comment above in the COUNT statement.